# Using stored procedures in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have very basic c# knowledge and have not used it in over a year, so I have come up with a small project that I would like to work through. I require some help with the stored procedures however:

I have a table which has already been set up as well as the connection to the DB

Table to store horses:

```
o   ID
o   Name(must be unique)
o   Age (Age can only be 1 - 17)
o   Member_ID
```

And I would like to perform the following stored procedures-

Create stored procedures to:

```
o   Insert Horse
o   Update Horse
o   Get Horse
```

At the moment this page is still empty:

`horse.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Horse.aspx.cs" Inherits="Horse" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Edit Horse Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Age" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`horse.aspx.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Horse : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I was thinking that the best way to display and edit the table would be to use a gridview but was not sure

What I would like to know is how to perform the different actions using the stored procedures

I will appreciate any input and thank you in advance

Comment: Although it doesn't seem it, this is a pretty big question. Too big for one SO post. In a nutshell, you'll need to set up a DB, access it and map it in your business layer to sensible classes however way you choose (ORM?), and that's before you even get to it on your 'front-end' code-behind like this.

Comment: Teach me programming generally is too broad. Grab a book. Learn your tools.

Comment: Hi @DeeMac the database has already been set up as well as the connections

Comment: So now you have to write your stored procedure, test it, establish a connection to your DB from your solution, test that, pull the results of the procedure into a list of classes in another class library project, test it, reference this project and your new method from your page load and bind the results to a repeater. And, of course, test it :) I can't elaborate any more sorry, SO is for specific questions, and this is too broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your stored procedure in SQL Server as:

```
CREATE PROC procTest
(
    @flag VARCHAR(1),
    @parameter1 VARCHAR(50),
    @paramter2 VARCHAR(25)  
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@flag='I')
    BEGIN
        -- insert statement
    END
    ELSE IF(@flag='U')
    BEGIN
        -- update statement
    END
    ELSE IF(@flag='D')
    BEGIN
        -- delete statement
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- select statement
        END
END
```

In your code behind create a method as below and call it from where you want :

```
public void Crud(string flag, string parameter1, string parameter2) 
 {
        // take ConnectionString as defined in your web.config or as per your requirement.
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = flag; // I for Insert/ U for Update/ D for delete/ S for select
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = parameter1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = parameter2;

        cn.Open();

        if (flag != "S")
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            // If you have grid view you can bind it here.
            gridView.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

        cn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

[How to execute stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx)

But maybe it will be better to use ORM, for example Entity Framework?